# Encode "ä", "ö", "ü" and "ß" in scheme (file-output-port)

Tags: scheme

I need to work with Files (Input and Output) containing the Symbols ÄäÖöÜüß and €. So it is possible to use the transcoders with the latin-1-codec or the utf-8-codec (utf-8 is perhaps the better option). I don't want to use the utf-16-codec. While the File-Input-Port works well ([Encode "ä", "ö", "ü" and "ß" in scheme (get german text from file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570176/encode-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-%C3%BC-and-%C3%9F-in-scheme-get-german-text-from-file)), I can't get the File-Output-Port working.

```
(define path ... <path to a txt-file containing this text: "äöüß">)

;; Input-Port works fine: 
(define fip (open-file-input-port
         path
         (file-options)
         (buffer-mode block)
         (make-transcoder (utf-8-codec))))

(get-string-all fip) ;; returns: "äöüß"

;; But Output-Port don't:
(define fop (open-file-output-port
         path
         (file-options no-fail)
         (buffer-mode block)
         (make-transcoder (utf-8-codec))))

(put-string fop "äöüß")
(close-port fop) ;; it stores just strange symbols in the txt-file
```

I don't know why it is not working. Trying to understand the problem i tried this:

```
(display (string->utf8 "ä")) -> #vu8 (239 191 189)
(utf8->string (string->utf8 "ä")) ;; returns a strange symbol
(utf8->string (string->utf8 "a")) ;; returns "a"

(utf8->string 
 (let-values (((p f) (open-bytevector-output-port
              (make-transcoder (utf-8-codec)))))
   (put-string p "a ä")
   (f))) ;; returns "a <strange symbol>"
```

I can read the Symbols "äöüß" but I can't write them via ports.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure whatever you're using to inspect the contents of the file it creates is treating it as UTF-8? (And that the original contents of the file are also encoded in UTF-8?)

Comment: `(string->utf8 "ä")` should be returning `#vu8(195 164)`, so there's definitely an encoding issue somewhere.

Comment: The [Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) is represented by that sequence of UTF-8 bytes... if your second code block is in a file, I bet it's not in UTF-8 and the chez reader replaces the invalid byte(s) with that codepoint.

Comment: Thank You Shawn. You are right. The problem is not the scheme code. I thought my code was wrong and it drove me crazy. The text-file where the ports are pointing to is a "normal" .txt-File with the encoding UTF-8. I use emacs 29.1 with "geiser chez" in windows 11. The encoding issue seems to to be buried somewhere in emacs. I tried set-language-enviroment "UTF-8" and "German", but it didn't work. Then I ran the scheme code in the Chez REPL directly from the terminal and voila: the encoding was correct. I think I will switch to another IDE. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

OK. Got it! The Problem was my IDE (emacs). The Solution was to include the following code to the .emacs-file:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
```

See also: https://goyoambrosio.com/2018/06/Dealing-with-utf-8-in-Emacs/